# What are the required steps for learning 3D animation?

Tags: animation

I want to develop 3D animations for scientific demonstrations. I am familiar with Java & C++.
I am not clear about the basics of 3D or 2D graphics, nor am I familiar with 3D animation tools like Blender and Maya, and I haven't been able to find any good resources for learning about these topics.
So, as a beginner what steps should I take to learn 3D graphics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to learn visualisation in a 3D Application (Maya, 3Dmax, Softimage, Blender aso) get this Software and read the manuals and visit the sites of the developer (eg. autodesk site, blender site).

In addition, there are a lot of forums with information (cgsociety aso) and tutorial sites in the internet. Buy books or learning dvd´s (for example from gnomon) with the needed topic.

Learn to model and how to make renderings (mental ray, vray) before you start with animation.

Learning 3D Graphics is a wide field and has a steep learning curve...

If you got a decent knowledge you can maybe apply to Animation Mentor...